# Failed building wheel for nes-py on windows

Tags: python

I'm trying to install nes-py for python with pip but and error happened when building the wheel. Can somebody help? The following is the log message. I'm using anaconda with python 3.7 with Windows 10.

```py
Collecting nes-py
  Using cached nes_py-8.1.8.tar.gz (76 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: gym>=0.17.2 in c:\users\11101\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nes-py) (0.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in c:\users\11101\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nes-py) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet<=1.5.11,>=1.4.0 in c:\users\11101\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nes-py) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.48.2 in c:\users\11101\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nes-py) (4.62.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\11101\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gym>=0.17.2->nes-py) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle<1.4.0,>=1.2.0 in c:\users\11101\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gym>=0.17.2->nes-py) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\11101\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyglet<=1.5.11,>=1.4.0->nes-py) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; platform_system == "Windows" in c:\users\11101\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tqdm>=4.48.2->nes-py) (0.4.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: nes-py
  Building wheel for nes-py (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\11101\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qvbmep16\\nes-py\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\11101\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qvbmep16\\nes-py\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\11101\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-r_06d3_5'
       cwd: C:\Users\11101\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qvbmep16\nes-py\
  Complete output (43 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py
  copying nes_py\nes_env.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py
  copying nes_py\_image_viewer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py
  copying nes_py\_rom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py
  copying nes_py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py\app
  copying nes_py\app\cli.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py\app
  copying nes_py\app\play_human.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py\app
  copying nes_py\app\play_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py\app
  copying nes_py\app\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py\app
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py\wrappers
  copying nes_py\wrappers\joypad_space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py\wrappers
  copying nes_py\wrappers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py\wrappers
  running build_ext
  building 'nes_py.lib_nes_env' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\mappers
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src\cartridge.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\cartridge.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src\controller.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\controller.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src\cpu.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\cpu.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src\emulator.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\emulator.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src\lib_nes_env.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\lib_nes_env.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src\main_bus.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\main_bus.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src\picture_bus.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\picture_bus.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src\ppu.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\ppu.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src/mappers\mapper_CNROM.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\mappers\mapper_cnrom.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src/mappers\mapper_NROM.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\mappers\mapper_nrom.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src/mappers\mapper_SxROM.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\mappers\mapper_sxrom.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN64 -Ines_py/nes/include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\include -c nes_py/nes/src/mappers\mapper_UxROM.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\mappers\mapper_uxrom.o -std=c++1y -march=native -pipe -O3
  writing build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\lib_nes_env.cp37-win_amd64.def
  C:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\g++.exe -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\cartridge.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\controller.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\cpu.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\emulator.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\lib_nes_env.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\main_bus.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\picture_bus.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\ppu.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\mappers\mapper_cnrom.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\mappers\mapper_nrom.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\mappers\mapper_sxrom.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\mappers\mapper_uxrom.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\nes_py\nes\src\lib_nes_env.cp37-win_amd64.def -LC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\libs -LC:\Users\11101\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 -lpython37 -lmsvcr140 -o build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\nes_py\lib_nes_env.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
  Cannot export PyInit_lib_nes_env: symbol not defined
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\11101\\Anaconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin\\g++.exe' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for nes-py
```

I have tried many fixes like changing the MANIFEST.in file, and some others, but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Visual C++, you can try this command:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

I resolved the same issue through this command.

Answer (score 0):

Could you install Visual C++ and try installing using pip? I had the same issue and it get resolved by that.